# Sending And Receiving Sockets (TCP/IP)

Tags: sockets, tcp, websocket

I know that it is possible that multiple packets would be stacked to the buffer to be read from and that a long packet might require a loop of multiple send attempts to be fully sent. But I have a question about packaging in these cases:

1. If I call *recv* (or any alternative (low-level) function) when there are multiple packets awaiting to be read, would it return them all stacked into my buffer or only one of them (or part of the first one if my buffer is insufficient)?
2. If I send a long packet which requires multiple iterations to be sent fully, does it count as a single packet or multiple packets? It's basically a question whether it marks that the package sent is not full?

These questions came to my mind when I thought about web sockets packaging. Special characters are used to mark the beginning and end of a packet which sorta leads to a conclusion that it's not possible to separate multiple packages.

P.S. All the questions are about TCP/IP but you are welcomed to share information (answers) about UDP as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP sockets are stream based. The order is guaranteed but the number of bytes you receive with each recv/read could be any chunk of the pending bytes from the sender. You can layer a message based transport on top of TCP by adding framing information to indicate the way that the payload should be chunked into messages. This is what WebSockets does. Each WebSocket message/frame starts with at least 2 bytes of header information which contains the length of the payload to follow. This allows the receiver to wait for and re-assemble complete messages.

For example, libraries/interfaces that implement the standard [Websocket API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) or a similar API (such as a browser), the onmessage event will fire once for each message received and the data attribute of the event will contain the entire message.

Note that in the older Hixie version of WebSockets, each frame was started with '\x00' and terminated with '\xff'. The current standardized IETF 6455 (HyBi) version of the protocol uses the header information that contains the length which allows much easier processing of the frames (but note that both the old and new are still message based and have basically the same API).

Answer (score 1):

TCP connection provides for *stream of bytes*, so treat it as such. No application message boundaries are preserved - one send can correspond to multiple receives and the other way around. You need loops on both sides.

UDP, on the other hand, is datagram (i.e. message) based. Here one read will always dequeue single datagram (unless you mess with low-level flags on the socket). Event if your application buffer is smaller then the pending datagram and you read only a part of it, the rest of it is lost. The way around it is to limit the size of datagrams you send to something bellow the normal MTU of 1500 (less IP and UDP headers, so actually 1472).